# rendering bitmap using Android ANativeWindow

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, video-streaming, android-camera

I'm experiencing an issue where the bitmap isn't rendered properly on the surfaceview.
the rendering is done in the native layer using ANativeWindow. to confirm the image I receive from the camera is good I have dumped the buffer on the filesystem and it looks good, but when trying to render it it is shown like the image below.

here is how I attempt to copy the bitmap to the ANativeWindow.

```
    static int counter = 0;
    std::string name =  "/sdcard/irImage" + std::to_string(counter++) + ".png";
    stbi_write_png(name.c_str(), WIDTH, HEIGHT, 4, mFormattedIRBuffer, WIDTH*4);

    ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;
    if (_window)
    {
        if (ANativeWindow_lock(_window, &buffer, NULL) == 0)
        {
            memcpy(buffer.bits, mFormattedIRBuffer, WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4);
            ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(_window);
        }
    }
```

[image]

when I try to render single colors (purple, yellow, pink) it displayed correctly on the surfaceview.

Any idea what I am missing here ?

UPDATE:

for some reason buffer.stride is differnt than buffer.width which i belive is causing the distortion on the surfaceview. the resolution i work with is 224x171
the stride appears to be 256. when working with higher resolution I don't have this problem. the stride is always the same as the width of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to overcome this problem of buffer.width being not the same as buffer.stride I had to pad the width of the image to match the stride. I had width = 224 and stride = 256 so I used padding of 16 on left and 16 on right. I am not sure if this is a limitation of ANativeWindow when working with low resolution images, but when I work with high resolution the width and strides are always equal